# chronometer in home screen widget - wrong count down format

Tags: android, chronometer, home-screen-widget

I have home screen widget which have one chronometer as RemoteViews item.
I need this chronometer to countdown from some time in the future. Chronometer works, but I have noticed some strange time formatings on some devices.
For example, if there is 10 minutes and 5 seconds remaining, I have following outputs:

Huawei Mate 10 Lite (Android Oreo - API 26)
 `-10:05`

Huawei G7, with Lollipop (API 22)
 `00:-605` -  total remaining time here is displayed as number of seconds.

My question: is there any way that I can provide my formating, so that result be same on all devices.

**NOTE:** I need this for chronometer in homescreen widget, not inside of an activity or a fragment.

Edit: Widget is refreshed from AlarmManager. On BroadcastReceiver I have following code to update widget.

```
protected void updateCountdownTimer(RemoteViews remoteViews, int index) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        List<Time> timeList;
        if (index == -1) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            TimesProvider.getProvider().setCurrentDate(calendar);
            index = 0;
        }
        timeList = TimesProvider.getProvider().getTimes();
        Time time = timeList.get(index);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.getMinute());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        remoteViews.setChronometer(R.id.chronometer, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis(), null, true);
        remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.chronometer, Color.CYAN);
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the code you used to do this ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén I had updated my question with some code where I initialize chronometer.